# REGEX URL (filter) DECIPHERING

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, filter

I'm trying to build a filter for a video list. I have managed to compose a string which contains the all the values that an user chooses for filtering. At this point i'm sending this string as an parameter through URL.

Example: http://example.dev/admin#/videos/status:3&site:4&categories:15,2,3&actors:33,5,36&search:Grass%20hopper%20/

**NOTE:** Note that the user may choose fewer filters, and therefore the 
parameter: `status:3&site:4&categories:15,2,3&actors:33,5,36&search:Grass%20hopper%20`, may differ, but the example above is the maximum combination.

**QUESTION: How do i get all the data using Regular Expressions (JS)?**

Preferable outcome: `['status=3', 'site=4', 'categories=15,2,3', 'actors=33,5,3', 'search=Grass hopper']`.

So far i have put this: `(\w+):(((\d+),)*(\d+)|(\d+))&*`, but not really know what to make of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this, but i'm not really sure what to make of it. I'm just trying out some combination on online regex tester. (\w+):(((\d+),)*(\d+)|(\d+))&*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only match digits with optional commas with your regex, but not values like `Grass hopper`.

You can match the key-values in the *last* `/.../` where the rightmost `/` is at the end of the string (if it can be absent, a `?` quantifier should be added after it).

Use

```
\w+:(?!\/\/)[^&]+(?=[^\/]*\/$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ5iH7/2).

*Explanation*:

- `\w+:` - 1+ alphanumerics or underscores followed with `:`
- `(?!\/\/)[^&]+` - 1+ characters other than `&` but not starting with `//` (to avoijd matching `http://`)
- `(?=[^\/]*\/$)` - a positive lookahead to check we are inside the last `/.../`.

```js
var re = /\w+:(?!\/\/)[^&]+(?=[^\/]*\/$)/g; 
var str = 'http://example.dev/admin#/videos/status:3&site:4&categories:15,2,3&actors:33,5,36&search:Grass hopper /';
var res= str.match(re);
if (res) {
  res = res.map(function (x) {return x.replace(":", "=")});
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
}
```

**Another solution** is to use a regex to only get the URL parts after `video/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM3gF4/1))

```
videos\/([^\/]+)
```

And then split the `match[1]` with `&`:

```js
var re = /videos\/([^\/]+)/; 
var str = 'http://example.dev/admin#/videos/status:3&site:4&categories:15,2,3&actors:33,5,36&search:Grass hopper /';
var m = str.match(re);
var res = [];
if (m) {
  res = m[1].split("&");
  res = res.map(x => x.replace(":", "="));
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Wow this works great. Can only the ':' be replaced to '='. So the outcome would look like ["status=3","site=4","categories=15,2,3","actors=33,5,36","search=Grass hopper "]

Comment: You mean you need to transform what you have in the input, right? Just add a `map` with `replace` inside to modify all the items in the array.